# strtok doesn't return any value

Tags: c, strtok

I want to write a programm that converts a string with numbers ("1 2 3") into an integer array. But strtok() doesn't return a value. Why not?
My console output is just empty.

Edit: I get no error message.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int* string_to_array(char * string, int * myArray);

int main(void) {
    int* myArray = 0;
    myArray = (int*) malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    myArray = string_to_array("1 2 3 4", myArray);

    printf("result: %d\n", myArray[0]);
    printf("result: %d\n", myArray[1]);
    return 0;
}

int* string_to_array(char * string, int * myArray){
    char delimiter[] = " ";
    char *ptr;
    char *ptr2;
    long ret;

    printf("string_to_array() was called.\n");
    printf("string is: %s\n", string);

    ptr = strtok(string, delimiter);            // here is the problem
    printf("strtok done; ptr: %s\n", ptr);

    int index = 0;
    while(ptr != NULL) {        
        ret = strtol(ptr, &ptr2, 10);
        printf("ret: %d\n", ret);
        myArray[index] = ret;
        ptr = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
        index++;
    }

    return myArray;
}
```

Comment: You cannot call `strtok` on string literals i.e.`"1 2 3 4"`. `strtok` modifies its first param. string literals are only to be read. Put `"1 2 3 4"` into char array.

Comment: @kame Use either sscanf or strspn and strcspn to extract numbers.

Comment: @rafix07 Sorry. I am still a beginner. I assumed string and char array is the same. But if not how are they different?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal

Comment: Aside: Consider the tidy: `myArray = malloc(sizeof *myArray * 10);` than `myArray = (int*) malloc(10 * sizeof(int));`.

Comment: kame,  "string and char array is the same. But if not how are they different?" --> [`What is the difference between char s[] and char *s?`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1704407/2410359)

Comment: @chux Should I remove (int*) in my code example?

Comment: @kame [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2410359) is an interesting read.  Yet I would not alter this question concerning that as it is a minor point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `strtol` is being use to parse the values, use `ptr2` to iterate through `string`. After a conversion, `ptr2` will point to the next character following the converted value. Use it as the starting point for the next conversion. More error checking can be done using `strtol`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int* string_to_array(char * string, int * myArray);

int main(void) {
    int* myArray = 0;
    myArray = (int*) malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    myArray = string_to_array("1 2 3 4", myArray);

    printf("result: %d\n", myArray[0]);
    printf("result: %d\n", myArray[1]);
    return 0;
}

int* string_to_array(char * string, int * myArray){
    char *ptr;
    char *ptr2;
    long ret;

    printf("string_to_array() was called.\n");
    printf("string is: %s\n", string);

    ptr = string;

    int index = 0;
    while(*ptr) {
        ret = strtol(ptr, &ptr2, 10);
        printf("ret: %ld\n", ret);
        myArray[index] = ret;
        ptr = ptr2;
        index++;
    }

    return myArray;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As [rafix07](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8950365/rafix07) wrote in his comment, you cannot use `strtok` with a string literal like `"1 2 3 4"`. On my system I get a segmentation fault in `strtok` because of this.

To use an array instead of a string literal you can modify your program like this:

```
int main(void) {
    int* myArray = 0;
    char input[] = "1 2 3 4"; /* This initializes a writable array with the string literal */

    myArray = (int*) malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    myArray = string_to_array(input, myArray); /* pass array instead of literal */

    printf("result: %d\n", myArray[0]);
    printf("result: %d\n", myArray[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Not that `strtok` modifies your original data. If you don't want this you can make your function `string_to_array` work on a copy of the data. With this modification you can call it with a string literal as in your original `main` function.

```
int* string_to_array(char * string, int * myArray){
    char delimiter[] = " ";
    char *ptr;
    char *ptr2;
    long ret;
    char *data;
    data = strdup(string);

    /* FIXME error handling for strdup */

    printf("string_to_array() was called.\n");
    printf("string is: %s\n", string);

    ptr = strtok(data, delimiter);            // here is the problem
    printf("strtok done; ptr(%p): %s\n", ptr, ptr);

    int index = 0;
    while(ptr != NULL) {        
        ret = strtol(ptr, &ptr2, 10);
        printf("ret: %ld\n", ret);
        myArray[index] = ret;
        ptr = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
        index++;
    }

    free(data);
    return myArray;
}
```

Note that you don't need to return the input pointer `myArray` from `string_to_array()` and assign it to `myArray` in `main()` because the original array is modified.

Your function `string_to_array()` doesn't know how big you allocated your array. I suggest to pass the number of elements as a function parameter and check that you don't write behind the end of the array. You also don't return the number of elements in `myArray` you actually filled with data, so your `main` function might access uninitialized elements.